# select2 change focus after select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

hey all so I have a few select2 option, after I select my first dropdown option it goes inside the event listener and printing "user selected". However the focus is not changing to the next select2. Much help would be appreciated thanks.

```
   <select id = "test1" required tabindex="1">
           <option value = '1'>item1 </option>
   </select>

     <select id = "test2" required tabindex="2">
            <option value = '2'>item1 </option>
    </select>

<select id="test3" required tabindex="3" style="width: 30%; height:36px;">
  <option value='1'>item1 </option>
  <option value='2'>item2 </option>
</select>

<select id="test4" required tabindex="4" style="width: 30%; height:36px;">
  <option value='1'>item1 </option>
  <option value='2'>item2 </option>
</select>

    $('#test1').select2({ });
    $('#test2').select2({ });
$('#test3').select2({});
$('#test4').select2({});

$('select').on('select2:select', function () {
  $(this).next('select').focus();

  // Do something
  console.log('user selected');
  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get reference of siblings select using `$(this).nextAll("select:first")` and then use `.select2("open")` to open your next select-box .

***Demo code*** :

```js
$('#test1').select2({});
$('#test2').select2({});
$('#test3').select2({});
$('#test4').select2({});

$('select').on('select2:select', function() {
  //use select or use select#yourid where you need to focus
  $(this).nextAll('select:first').select2('open');
  console.log('user selected');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="test1" required tabindex="1" style="width: 30%; height:36px;">
  <option value='1'>item1 </option>
  <option value='2'>item2 </option>
</select>

<select id="test2" required tabindex="2" style="width: 30%; height:36px;">
  <option value='2'>item1 </option>
  <option value='5'>item5</option>
</select>
<select id="test3" required tabindex="2" style="width: 30%; height:36px;">
  <option value='2'>item1 </option>
  <option value='5'>item5</option>
</select>
<select id="test4" required tabindex="2" style="width: 30%; height:36px;">
  <option value='2'>item1 </option>
  <option value='5'>item5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, however this only works for 2 select. How would you change it so that it works for  more like for 4 selects. (just edited the post) sorry I should've made 4 in my og post instead of 2